# Open & write to a file-like object but avoid AttributeError about missing open()

Tags: python, file

I want to have function that can write content into a file-like object. It accepts `pathlib.Path` objects or `io.StringIO`. The first one need to be `open()`'ed first, the second one not.

Because of that it seems to me I have to explicte type check the object to know if I have to call `open()` on it or not.

Is there an elegant and pythonic way to work around this?

Here is an MWE.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import io
import pathlib
import typing

def foobar(file_like_obj: typing.Union[pathlib.Path, typing.IO]):
    with file_like_obj.open('w') as handle:
        handle.write('foobar')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = pathlib.Path.home() / 'my.txt'
    foobar(p)

    sio = io.StringIO()
    foobar(sio)
```

The second call of `foobar()` here cause this error:

```
AttributeError: '_io.StringIO' object has no attribute 'open'
```

One pythonic-like way I know to prevent explicit type checking is to use `try-except` blocks. But this would break my `with` block.

Comment: A simple workaround is to refactor your function to process an opened file handle, and delegate the opening to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

The [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74900422/open-write-to-a-file-like-object-but-avoid-attributeerror-about-missing-open#comment132180052_74900422) from [@tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee) inspired me to this approach which I wouldn't call a solution because it doesn't fit to all needs in my opening question. But it seems as a good compromise to me.

I combined recursive calls and a `try..except` block. The recursion is because I didn't want to separate the functionality into a second function.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import io
import pathlib
import typing

def foobar(file_like_obj: typing.Union[pathlib.Path, typing.IO]):
    print('foobar(): called')

    try:

        with file_like_obj.open('w') as handle:
            print('re-call myself')

            foobar(handle)

    except AttributeError:
        file_like_obj.write('foobar')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = pathlib.Path.home() / 'my.txt'
    foobar(p)

    sio = io.StringIO()
    foobar(sio)
```

The output

```
foobar(): called
re-call myself
foobar(): called
foobar(): called
```